# Add As clause to function

Tags: vb.net

It says i need to add As caluse to this function.

I tried to go As Boolean() but seems like a not option

```
Public Function HasConnection()
        Try
            sqlcon.Open()
            sqlcon.Close()
            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function
```

Comment: it's `Public Function HasConnection() As Boolean`, not `As Boolean()`

Comment: `As Boolean()` would mean it returns an array of bools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
Public Function HasConnection() As Boolean
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean not an option?

```
Public Function HasConnection() As Boolean
        Try
            sqlcon.Open()
            sqlcon.Close()
            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            Return False
        End Try
End Function
```